# How to extract result from SpeechRecognizer - Android

Tags: android

Im sending intent to use speech recognizer

```
val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH).apply {
        putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
        putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.US) 
        putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, R.string.speech_prompt)
    }
    startForResult.launch(intent)
```

But how can I extract the results from it? I've tried several way

```
private val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
    result: ActivityResult ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("testing","resultData ${result.data}")//here I see HAS EXTRAS    
        result.data.let {
          inputField.setText(it?.getStringArrayExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)?.get(0))

      //I've used this one and it doesn't work as well
                 inputField.setText(it?.getStringArrayExtra(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION)?.get(0))

        }
    }
}
```

So what is the correct way to extract the result ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that works for me

```
private val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
    result: ActivityResult ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        myInput.setText(result.data?.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)?.first())
    }
}
```